# Is there another way of passing user's parameters to program other than through main's argv?

Tags: c, parameters, console, arguments, program-entry-point

Is there any other way of passing user's parameters into a program other than through

> ./program argument1 argument2

where `argument1` and `argument2` will be passed on to `main`'s `argv[]`?

Comment: You can read them from somewhere.

Comment: Our answers might differ if we knew why you are looking for an alternative way to pass parameters to a program.

Comment: You can read from a file or environment variables, but those will not be passed to `argv[]`.

Comment: @MathieuPagé It's an exam question.

Comment: Say `argument1 argument2` are smallish numbers 0 to 59, then with careful _timing_ of the start of code, the app could read the time and get the minutes/seconds as information.  Certainly not fool-proof - jut living outside the box.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That is, of course, technically right and also kind of clever.

Comment: There are many ways to leak information from one system to another.  One could affect other data sources, (event queues, [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) or perhaps, re-write the executable).  Yet since this is exam related, prof is likely looking for the [usual suspects (0:45)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXuBnz6vtuI),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application could read the values from the standard input, a configuation file or even environnent variables.

Comment: or from a config file, for that matter.

Comment: Environment variables could also be an option (albeit probably not a good one depending on the circumstance).